# Routing ports on a private IP to different addresses in Azure

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, routing, port-forwarding, azure-networking

Is there a way to route requests to the same private IP address to different targets depending on port used within Azure?

## Context

We have a VM which serves content on SFTP (SSH; not FTPS) and HTTP.

These services are exposed publicly on the same public hostname.

To improve security I've associated a public IP with an instance of Azure Firewall, and used DNAT to route port 22 to the VM, whilst routing ports 80 and 443 on to an Application Gateway, which redirects requests on port 80 to the listener for 443, and performs TLS offloading for requests on 443 passing the HTTP request on to the backend VM.

I've now been asked to amend the SFTP configuration so that only 2 external clients can connect to the SFTP service; whilst continuing to allow internal clients to access SFTP and everyone to access HTTPS.

Whitelisting only the public IPs for the external clients is straightforwards; but because the firewall has a public IP, all internal requests are routed out to the internet first, so our internal users aren't showing up in private IP ranges, but also show with public IPs.  We have users in multiple countries and using different VPN services (depending on their country) meaning that simply whitelisting the breakout points for users connections isn't straightforwards (i.e. there's 1 breakout per country, and users using VPN would show under their own IPs as we don't override routing for public IPs in our VPN; only private ones).

I'd hoped I could dedicate a private IP to this same hostname, setting that up on our private DNS, so that when users are internal they're routed to the private IP; but with this IP resolving to the same firewall, with the DNAT rules then allowing the SFTP vs HTTP(S) requests to be routed as we've done with the public IP.

I can't just use the backend VM's IP or we'd bypass the TLS offloading done by the app gateway / would end up with HTTP connections.

I have to use the same hostname for both SFTP and HTTP(S) endpoints, and thus have to have both on the same IP (since DNS isn't aware of port/protocol).

Any suggestions on a way to achieve this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to to create a few extra DNS zones, something like *.sftp-external.com *.sftp-internal.com, then you would be able to add the same host to both dns zones and the IP. (Split-brain DNS). You could also make the internal zone only resolvable internal with the proper nameserver configuration. It might be also an option to create a storage account with public access and [SFTP enabled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-support) for the external users. That saves you a lot of work with DNS.

Comment: Thanks Ace; sadly the SFTP service is part of an existing system (built in / tightly coupled) / not something we can swap out for a different SFTP solution.  DNS isn't the issue here, rather it's the routing of 2 different services on the same internal hostname/IP; i.e. so that HTTP(S) traffic gets sent via the app gateway, whilst SFTP gets routed direct to the backend VM

Comment: Have you tried creating a rule in Azure Firewall that forwards port 22 to the SFTP service and 443 to the App Gateway? Ideally the vnets of the App Gateway and the SFTP service are peered with the Hub network of the Azure Firewall, otherwise it won't work either. (the sftp and app gateway subnets can be seen as spokes)

Comment: yes, that's how it's setup.  The issue is that the SFTP we only want to be accessible to 2 external IPs and anyone internal... but everyone internal shows up as having an external IP as the service is public facing (so their connections go out to come back)... and bypassing the firewall via DNS doesn't help unless we were to point internal users directly to the backend server & thus have to manage SSL certificates for the site on there as well as on the app gateway (something we're trying to avoid as part of our strategy to manage certs in fewer places)

Comment: I would suggeest to look into UDR's (user defined routes) to properly route your internal traffic and bypass the firewall. @JohnLBevan